# Adding labels on x-axis

Tags: zedgraph

I have a `String[] label = {"Dogs", "Cats", "Birds", "Pigs"};`

I have a graph, and I want the labes to show at x, y on the x-axis, and not at random places. As an example, I have a curve, and dogs should appear at `x = 3 and y = 8`, and cats at `x = 5 and y = 12` etc. How can I achieve this?

Right now to add the labels, I am doing:

```
graphPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = label;
```

and this adds the labels with out a system.

Comment: Did you manage to do it ?